# Python return eval value within function?

Tags: python, function, eval

```
def input():
    h = eval(input("Enter hours worked: \n"))
    return h

def main():
    hours = input()
    print(hours)  
main()
```

As you can tell, I'm new to Python.  I keep getting: "TypeError: input() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)."  Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated -- thank you all very much!

Comment: input is a method in python and it takes 1 argument. try to use another name for your function `def input()`

Comment: Thank you islandmyth -- that was it.  I renamed the function and all is well.

Comment: Don't use `eval()` for this. `int()` or `float()` will probably work for you. `eval()` is extremely dangerous to use with user input. eg try entering `help(__import__('os').removedirs)`

Answer (score 2):

You define a function called `input` in the first line that takes zero arguments and then when you call the `input` function later (which I assume you intended it to call the one that comes with Python and may have accidentally overridden) you pass it one variable.

```
# don't try to override the buil-in function
def input_custom():
    h = eval(input("Enter hours worked: \n"))
    return h

def main():
    hours = input_custom()
    print(hours)  
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

`input()` is the name of a builtin Python function.

In your code, you override it, which is definitely not a good idea. Try naming your function something else:

```
def get_hours():
    h = eval(input("Enter hours worked: \n"))
    return h

def main():
    hours = get_hours()
    print(hours)  

main()
```

Comment: This depends on the Python version, but the OP appears to be using print as a function, which implies Py3. But, more importantly, this doesn't explain the particular error the OP is getting.

Answer (score 1):

Change your input function with a different name since input is a method in python.

```
def inputx():
     h = eval(input("Enter hours worked: \n"))
     return h

 def main():
     hours = inputx()
     print(hours)

 main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your exact error - instead I get:

```
TypeError: input() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

But, your error is likely caused by the same thing - when you name your function `input`, you shadow the built-in `input`: Python can't see both, even though yours doesn't expect a prompt. If you name yours `myinput` instead, Python can tell the difference:

```
def myinput():
    h = eval(input("Enter hours worked: \n"))
    return h

def main():
    hours = myinput()
    print(hours)  
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have covered a lot.. I would just like add some thoughts to it.
First of all your function name input is overriding the python builtin function

so first of all

```
def my_input():
    return input("Enter hours worked: ")
print my_input()
```

This should suffice.

**Concept:**

Now if you are using **Python 2.X** version then there is no need for eval.

*input():* Python by default evaluates the input expression if it is recognized by python.

*raw_input():* Here the input is taken as a string which needs to be evaluated.

In case of **Python3.x:**

*input()* behaves like *raw_input()* and *raw_input()* is removed.

So your code should be

```
def my_input():
    return float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
print(my_input())
```

It is safer and better way to take inputs and also tells us why eval is not recommended.

> You don't know what's gonna come through that door.

Thank you.