# How to return a value while using eval in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a String that contains Python code as below.
The Python's features I am implementing to run the String containing Python code are `eval` and `exec`

```
from CodeExecs.Compilers import Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4, Code5, Code6, Code7, Code8, Code9, Code10, Code11, Code12, Code13, Code14, Code15, Code16, Code17, Code18, Code19, Code20
program = """for i in range(1, 21):\n\tif eval(f'Code{i}().load(jobj)'): return 'True'\n\telse: return 'False'"""
print(exec(program))
```

If the for-loop in `program` appears obscure, it could be found in the error message at the bottom.
The above code prints `True` when the case is satisfied (Code1 & Code2). The expression in eval raises an exception for `Code3`.

So instead of printing, if I try to return `True` / `False` as below:

```
program = """for i in range(1, 21):\n\tif eval(f'Code{i}().load(jobj)'): return 'True'\n\telse: return 'False'"""
print(exec(program))
```

I see an error:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Below is the full console log with error message.

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    if eval(f'Code{i}().load(jobj)'): return 'True'
    else: return 'False'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/CodeValidation/CheckSchema.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(exec(program))
  File "<string>", line 2
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I return `True` or `False` in my case as given above?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python return eval value within function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844331/python-return-eval-value-within-function)

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Just put the 20 `Code` classes in a list: `for c in [Code1, ..., Code20]: if c().load(obj): return 'True'`.

Comment: Also, once you return anything, the loop will exit if it's inside a function

Comment: As the error points out: Your code string isn't embedded in a function from which it could return something. And as @LuisAFK pointed out: Even if it were, the loop would stop in the first iteration because of the return.

Comment: @Timus & LuisAFK, I recently started Python and got to know the availability of this feature the day I posted this question. Hence the confusion.

Comment: @chepner This worked without as I was expecting & its simple too. Even though it is not using eval/exec, I think its simple to understand. Can you make this an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store your classes in a list to iterate over.

```
from CodeExecs.Compilers import Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4, Code5, Code6, Code7, Code8, Code9, Code10, Code11, Code12, Code13, Code14, Code15, Code16, Code17, Code18, Code19, Code20


def something():
    return all(c().load(jobj) for c in [Code1, Code2, ..., Code20])
```